# What are the pricing and limits on number and duration of entries for a foreigner applying for a Chinese visa in Mexico?

Tags: visas, china, regulations, mexico, price

I'm about to book a side trip from China to Mexico and back. From experience both the prices and the number of entries and duration per entry China will grant you actually vary quite a bit depending on where you are from and in what country you apply for your Chinese visa. For instance:

- The times I got my Chinese visas in Laos they were half the price or less than what I paid in Australia.
- But this time in Australia I was granted 60 days per entry.
- Once I changed my plan to get a Chinese visa in Vietnam because they would give me only one 30-day entry. I went back to Laos and got two 30-day entries.

What really are my options at the consulate in Mexico?

Answer (score 3):

Check the web page of the [EMBAJADA DE LA REPUBLICA POPULAR CHINA EN LOS ESTADOS UNIDOS MEXICANOS](http://mx.china-embassy.org/esp/LSFW/consular1/t1156489.htm) because they have different types of visa, separated by number of entries or exits, and for nationalities that request the visa. But the average price is about from 1890 MXN to 2180 MXN (about 90 to 103 USD).

Comment: Average price? Not for Australians, for one and two entries it's 510 and 730 MXN. That's $24 to $34 USD and quite cheap indeed. I thought I had asked specifically about Australians and the question had been changed, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything about the duration of entries.

Answer (score 2):

The [Chinese Embassy in Mexico](http://mx.china-embassy.org/esp/LSFW/consular1/t1156489.htm) has a fairly detailed page on visa types and fees, separated by passport type. I'm not sure if you're guaranteed to receive one if you apply as a foreigner, but that's as best as you can get from the officials.

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything about the duration of entries.